# Getting Security Error on iPhone when using localStorage

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, local-storage

When I try saving anything with `localStorage.setItem("");` in IOS Safari, I get this error -

> SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.

Here is a screenshot of the error...

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: By default, Safari doesn't allow access to local files. Try to enable it by setting [Disable local file restrictions](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/safari/use-the-safari-develop-menu-sfri20948)

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying I can't store any Cookies on IOS?

Comment: Maybe you need to use the [document.requestStorageAccess()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/requestStorageAccess) api

Answer (score 15):

Found the answer. **Block Cookies** was turned on in the users Safari Settings.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on the desktop version of Safari. I enabled "Disable Local File Restrictions" This is how you can find it:

[image: where to find "disable local file restrictions" in desktop safari]

Your cookie settings are also not allowed to be on "Always block". Otherwise you also get this error!

Comment: Okay but we can't just tell all of our users to do this...

Answer (score 1):

It's not only Safari, but also Firefox in private browsing mode.
Chrome doesn't block localStorage in incognito mode, but it is being reset at each session (which is a better option imho).
In either case, you shouldn't use localStorage directly, but instead make a script that uses it if it is available, and if not, then use sessionStorage.
I.e.

```
var backupStorage = {};
var storageMode = 'localStorage';
try {
    localStorage.length;
} catch(e) {
    try {
        sessionStorage.length;
        storageMode = 'sessionStorage';
    } catch(e) {
        storageMode = 'backupStorage';
    }
}

function setLocalStorage(key, value) {
    switch(storageMode) {
        case 'localStorage':
            localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            break;
        case 'sessionStorage':
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
            break;
        case 'backupStorage':
            backupStorage[key] = value;
            break;
    }
}
function getLocalStorage(key) {
    switch(storageMode) {
        case 'localStorage':
            return localStorage.getItem(key);
        case 'sessionStorage':
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        case 'backupStorage':
            return backupStorage[key];
    }
}
```